# to identify if the data have certain words and label them TRUE if they have FALSE if they don't have

Tags: r

body : c(" i want a computer", "use my laptop", "buy a macbook", "found a good deal on macbook and windows laptop")

I want to identify if these posts have certain words and label them TRUE if they have FALSE if they don't have. Results would look sth like this.
lets' say there are the words i need R to identify for me ;
words_to_be_identified : ("Computer", "laptop", "MacBook")

Results should look like this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ewbU.png)

Body: c(" i want a computer", "use my laptop", "buy a macbook", "found a good deal on macbook and windows laptop")

Computer : TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE

laptop: FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE

MacBook : FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE

Multiple: FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE

Comment: Look at the help file : `?grepl`

Comment: It really would be rather easy to whip up some code that does that, Reshmi Kumpakha, but I'm not going to transcribe data from an image into something to use. Can you please add *real sample data*, either programmatically (`dat <- c("hello","world")`) or by posting the output from `dput(dat)`. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you allan and r2evans, grepl function was useful.